# python decorators not taking the value from constant passed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

***report.py***

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, description = "CHECK-ACCESS REPORTING.")
    parser.add_argument('--input','-i', help='Filepath containing the Active Directory userlist')
    parser.add_argument('--timestamp', '-t', nargs='?',const="BLANK", help='filepath with environement varible set')        
    args, unknownargs = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])

    timestampchecker(args.timestamp)
    #checking the value of cons.DISPLAYRESULT is TRUE        
    main()
```

***timestampchecker function :***

```
def timestampchecker(status):
    """ Check if the timestamp is to display or not from command line"""
    if status is not None:
        cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP = True
```

This function checks if the user have set the   **-t** arguments. If it is set I have defined one constant called **cons.DISPLAYRESULT** to true.

The function is working great and turning the constant value to True.
But in the main function I have implemented this decorators which is not taking the true value but false

***timer.py***

```
def benchmarking(timestaus):
    def wrapper(funct):
        def timercheck(*args, **kwarg):
            if timestaus is True:
                starttime=time.time()
            funct(*args, **kwarg)
            if timestaus is True:
                print('Time Taken:',round(time.time()-starttime, 4))
        return timercheck
    return wrapper
```

I have decorated some method in main() method of report.py with the decorators above. For example This is the class being used in report.py and being decorated with above decorators

```
class NotAccountedReport:

    def __init__(self, pluginoutputpath):
        """ Path where the plugins result are stored need these files"""

        self.pluginoutputpath = pluginoutputpath

    @benchmarking(cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP)
    def makeNotAccountableReport():
        #some functionality
```

> here I have passed the constant value to the argument decorator which
>   when tested though before called is converted to True is taking false
>   and thus the decorators not being implemented. Where is the problem
>   cant figure out

Comment: This is a trivial point, but maybe I am not understanding your last paragraph. When you say "I have passed the constant value to the argument decorator" do you mean `@benchmarking(const)`? Then `const is True` and `bool(const) is True` will have different outcomes.

Comment: I  mean to say I have defined the constant and that value is what the decorators is being passed. The decorators runs only when that value is set to `True`. But what is happening is thought the constant value is change to True the decorator is being loaded first and taking the `False` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post a complete minimal verifiable example so there might be something else too, but if your point is that when calling `NotAccountedReport().makeNotAccountableReport()` you don't get your "Time taken" printed then it's really not a surprise - the `benchmarking` decorator is applied when the function is defined (when the module is imported), well before the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause is executed, so at that time `cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP` has not been updated by your command line args.

If you want a runtime flag to activate / deactivate your decorator's behaviour the obvious solution is to check `cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP` within the decorator instead of passing it as argument, ie:

```
def benchmarking(func):
    def timercheck(*args, **kwarg):
        if cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP:
           starttime=time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwarg)
        if cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP:
            logger.debug('Time Taken: %s',round(time.time()-starttime, 4))
        return result  
    return timercheck


class NotAccountedReport(object):
    @benchmarking
    def makeNotAccountableReport():
        #some functionality
```

Comment: Thats exactly the problem is . So what can be done for the solutions. The `cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP` is updated but is as you mentioned the decorators is taking value before the function is get called in `if __name__=='__main__'. Any solutions for it

Comment: Well it seems quite obvious : don't pass `cons.DISPLAY_TIME_STAMP` as argument to your decorator, just check it directly, cf my edited answer.